# Jquery, get results from php to <li> in this example

Tags: php, jquery, smarty

So this is full voting system, but now i need to get results from php and input them to current-rating class in place of {$SCORE} below. Need some help, as always I am gratefull.

HTML in loop (smarty):

```
<ul class="star-rating" id="{$ID}">
<li class="current-rating" style="width:{$SCORE}%;"></li>
<li><a href="#" class="one-star"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="two-stars"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="three-stars"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="four-stars"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="five-stars"></a></li>
</ul>

<div style="display:none;" id="msgOK-{$ID}">Vote</div>
<div style="display:none;" id="msgWRONG-{$ID}">Wrong</div>
<div style="display:none;" id="msgLOGIN-{$ID}">Login</div>
```

Jquery:

```
   $(function() {

    $('ul.star-rating').on('click', 'a', function() { // jquery 1.7+

      var score = this.className,
      id = $(this).closest('ul')[0].id;

      $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",
            url: "js/ajax.php",
            data: {id: id, score: score},
            success: function(pass) {
                if(pass == '1') {
                          // all ok
                     $("div#msgOK-" + id).delay(200).fadeIn(2000).delay(3000).fadeOut(2000);
                     $("ul.star-rating#" + id).hide(100).delay(7100).show('fast');
                } else if(pass == '2') { 
                          // something went wrong
                     $("div#msgWRONG-" + id).delay(200).fadeIn(2000).delay(3000).fadeOut(2000);
                     $("ul.star-rating").hide(100).delay(7100).show('slow');
                } else if(pass == '3') {
                             // you need to be logged in to vote
                     $("div#msgLOGIN-" + id).delay(200).fadeIn(2000).delay(3000).fadeOut(2000);
                     $("ul.star-rating").hide(100).delay(7100).show('slow');
                }
             }
          });
         return false;
       });
    });
```

Comment: you are using smarty? also what problem you are facing

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you just looking for: `style="width:<?php echo $SCORE ?>;"`?

Comment: After subbmiting vote thru Jquery, in $("ul.star-rating#" + id) i show stars block again. The problem is that, before i show whoole block "I need to get current results from php" and set current-rating with new number. So ppl would see change, not just after they refresh site manually :)

Answer (score 1):

Why you have a userscore inside a css width I'm not sure but here is how you would insert the new rating into the css width property.  Inside your success function add the following:

```
  success: function(pass) {
            //you need to make 'pass' an object on your php side with fields
            //more on that below
            if(pass.errorlvl == '1') {
              $(".current-rating").css('width', pass.userscore );
              $("div#msgOK-" + id).delay(200).fadeIn(2000).delay(3000).fadeOut(2000);
              $("ul.star-rating#" + id).hide(100).delay(7100).show('fast');
            }
            ....
```

your php should make 'pass' into an object (or associative array) like so:

```
 $myerror_lvl = 1
 $new_score = "3.5"
 return array("errorlvl": $myerror_lvl, "userscore": $new_score);
```

Comment: well, managed to do it, basicly what i needed was "css width". thx.